# Can I pass in "just now" as a time for JQuery Timeago?

Tags: jquery, timezone, timeago

I'm using JQuery timeago to make my dates pretty (eg. "1 day ago"). Is there a keyword for "just now" or do I have to pass in the javascript calculated time to PHP?

```
 <abbr class='timeago' title='What do I put here?'>Just Now</abbr>
```

Comment: Couldn't you try "just now" and see? A little debugging goes a long way...

Comment: What would be the point of using the `timago` library? Couldn't you just set the text to "Just Now" using plain 'ol JavaScript (or even plain 'ol jQuery if you want).

Comment: "just now" didn't work. I'm using timeago because it auto-updates, so if they stay on the page for a minute, it will change from "just now" to "about a minute ago" to "5 minutes ago" or whatever automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery to insert the timestamp for you.

```
var justnow = ISODateString(new Date());
$('abbr[title="just now"]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', justnow);
});
```

Where ISODateString is:

```
function ISODateString(d) {
    function pad(n) {
        return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n
    }
    return d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(d.getUTCDate()) + 'T' + pad(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' + pad(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + pad(d.getUTCSeconds()) + 'Z';
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/RZXzL/

Comment: your fiddle works for me, despite the time being 4 hours fast. On my dev, however, UTC wouldn't work (maybe because my server and I are EDT?). I changed your code to exclude the "UTC" from the functions (leaving "getFullYear", "getMonth" etc), and it's working now (thanks). Do you see any issues with that?

Comment: No, I think that should be fine.